# Javascript simple dice object with roll & display functions

Tags: javascript, dice

I NEED TO CREATE A DICE OBJECT, so how can I include a dice object into this code?

I am creating a very simple dice roll in javascript. I have to have a dice object with an attribute named value, a roll method, and a printDie method which shows the two die numbers on the page. When I try this code I get "undefined." Any help is appreciated, thank you!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
// dice object attribute named value, method printDie, method roll
function dice(value){
    this.value = value;
    this.roll = function(roll){
    }
    this.printDie = function(printDie){
    }
}

function roll(){
    var die = Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+1;
    return die;
}
function printDie(){
    this.roll();

    var die1 = document.getElementById('die1');
    var die2 = document.getElementById('die2');

    die1.innerHTML = die1.value;
    die2.innerHTML = die2.value;

}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<button onClick="printDie()">Roll Dice</button>
<h1 id="die1"></h1>&nbsp;&nbsp;<h1 id="die2"></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where do you get the undefined error?

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code, the first of which is the use of the this keyword, which will only work if you are making an instance of dice. Also, you are not capturing the result of the `roll` method.

Look at the comments below for more issues:

```
 // dice object attribute named value, method printDie, method roll
 function dice(value){

     // The only way the use of the word this will help you here
     // is if the function is called as a constructor (var d = new dice())
     // Because that's not the case, this refers to the global window
     // object, which does not have a value property
     this.value = value;

     // Here, you are adding a roll property to the global window object
     // and assigning a function to it
     this.roll = function(roll){
     }

     // Here, you are creating a printDie property on the global window object
     this.printDie = function(printDie){
     }
 }


 // if this function is a function of the dice, it should be added to the
 // dice.prototype as in: dice.prototype.roll = function () { var die = . . . }
 function roll(){
     var die = Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+1;
     return die;
 }
 function printDie(){
     // You are calling roll(), which returns a value, but you are not 
     // capturing that value? Also, no need for this.roll(), use just roll()
     this.roll();

     var die1 = document.getElementById('die1');
     var die2 = document.getElementById('die2');

     die1.innerHTML = die1.value;
     die2.innerHTML = die2.value;

 }
```

Also, as an FYI, you really should avoid inline HTML event handlers (onclick="") as they create spaghetti code and cause the code you supplied as a value for onclick to be wrapped in a global function, which causes problems if/when the keyword this is used within the callback code. Instead, wire event handlers using the DOM Event Model standard (via JavaScript)

```
     element.addEventListener("eventName", callbackFunction);
```

Comment: Actually the dice object is not used. If invoked with `new dice(x)` it would allow this.value to be set

Comment: Yes, but that's not what the OP is showing. No need to down vote!

Comment: @mplungjan I sure am if you bother to READ the entire post. Problem is that the return value from roll is not captured.

Comment: @mplungjan I have not changed the OP's code at all. I have added comments explaining where the issues are. Stop acting like the SO police. My points are correct.

Comment: I do need a "new dice"! That's what I forgot.

Comment: @mplungjan Please read the comment from ronjdv,  above this one and stop injecting invalid, hair-splitting comments. I'll take that upvote now by the way, since my answer was updated as you suggested.

Comment: @mplungjan Actually, roll should be added to dice.prototype and be left outside of the dice constructor.

Comment: Does your code run? You still have a this.roll() which is not what is meant since it is doing a window.roll() instead of a dice.roll()

Comment: @mplungjan You still haven't really read anything I've posted have you?  I have not changed the OP's code in any way! I don't have a this.roll, the OP does and if you READ the comments, you'll see that I've already pointed out that this.roll means window.roll. READ!

Comment: I READ - I do not see SOLUTIONS, only MORE CODE that STILL does NOT WORK!

Comment: OP is not asking for solutions. He's asking for help understanding why his code doesn't work. Of course the code doesn't work. It's the ORIGINAL CODE!

Comment: "so how can I include a dice object into this code" - you are not answering the question and some comments are wrong _// Because that's not the case, this refers to the global window
     // object, which does not have a value property
     this.value = value;_ is incorrect. When the dice function is called with new dice(), this.value is a member of the dice object and not the window object

Answer (score -1):

Here is working code

I now invoke the object and chain it in the die.roll().printDie()

I also changed the type of button to button to stop submission in some browsers. All the methods are now local to the object you need to create and the click is moved out of the button.

```js
function Dice() {
  this.die = [];
  this.roll = function(roll) {
    this.die = [Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1, Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1]
    return this; // for chaining
  }
  this.printDie = function() {
    document.getElementById('die1').innerHTML = this.die[0];
    document.getElementById('die2').innerHTML = this.die[1];
  }
  return this;
}

window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("rollBut").onclick=function() {
    var die = new Dice()
    die.roll().printDie();
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="rollBut">Roll Dice</button>
<h1 id="die1"></h1>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<h1 id="die2"></h1>
```

Comment: The OP wants to know why the code doesn't work. He's not asking you to write a new solution. You don't explain anything in this answer. Not very helpful.

Comment: You still aren't explaining anything about the problems with the original code, which is what the OP is asking about. You don't even explain your new version of the code!

Comment: Now methinks it is you who is argumentative

Comment: There really is no argument. Just facts.